# Tooltip content as table on PrimeNG tree node

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

My application has PrimeNG Tree and the requirement is to show a tooltip in tabular format on Tree Node. Please refer attached screenshot[image]

Any help on this is appreciated.